# How can I get HttpAsyncClient to act asynchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use HttpAsyncClient to stress test my web application by submitting a hundred or thousand HTTP requests a second and timing the response for each one.  My code is based on [this quickstart guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/quickstart.html) but it seems that the thread that connects to the server and sends the HTTP request then sits there waiting for the response from the server!  Instead I want it to continue sending next HTTP request *without waiting for a HTTP response*.

Here is my test code:

```
public class TestAsyncHttpRequest {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
        try {
            // Start the client
            httpclient.start();
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println("Sending POST request at "
                        + FORMAT.format(new Date()));
                final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                        "http://localhost:8080/test");
                httpclient.execute(request, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

                    public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                    public void cancelled() {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                });
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            latch.await();
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding test servlet just print the time of the request and then sleeps for 20 seconds:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().log(
                "TestServlet Received POST at: " + fmt.format(new Date()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

The servlet output is as follows - notice that it is only receiving two requests every 20 seconds:

```
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:16.838
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:16.838
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:36.873
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:36.873
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:56.881
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:01:56.881
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:02:16.891
INFO: TestServlet Received POST at: 2014-03-28 07:02:16.891
```

Is there some configuration option that will allow me to send a thousand HTTP requests to the server without spawning lots of threads?

Answer (score 2):

`HttpAsyncClient` has limits for total number of concurrent connections and number of concurrent connections per host.

Try to increase them:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
    .setMaxConnTotal(100)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(100)
    .build();
```

Comment: Oh yes! So it seems, so the limiting factor for me was the mac connections per route, which defaults to 2?!?!